# RuntimeError: size mismatch (got input: [3], target: [64])

Tags: python, pytorch

i'm using batch_size = 64,and num_labels = 3

this is my dataset class

```
class CurseDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = labels 
        self.labels_num = len(self.labels)
        print('labels_num:', self.labels_num)

    def __getitem__(self, idx): 
        input_ids = torch.tensor(self.encodings['input_ids'][idx])
        token_type_ids = torch.tensor(self.encodings['token_type_ids'][idx])
        attention_mask = torch.tensor(self.encodings['attention_mask'][idx])
        labels = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask,labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
```

and i make a train dataloader and test dataloader model as well

and this is my model class

```
import torch
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, pretrained_model):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.pretrained_model = pretrained_model
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 

        N_h = 3
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3, N_h)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(N_h)  
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(N_h, N_h)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(N_h)  
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(N_h, 3)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        print(inputs)
        outputs = self.pretrained_model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.logits
        print("Logits shape:", logits.shape)
        x = self.fc1(logits)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        print(x)
        print(x.shape)
        print("Input size of fc1 layer:", self.fc1.in_features)
        print("Weight size of fc1 layer:", self.fc1.weight.size())
        print("Input size of fc1 layer:", self.fc2.in_features)
        print("Weight size of fc1 layer:", self.fc2.weight.size())
        print("Input size of fc1 layer:", self.fc3.in_features)
        print("Weight size of fc1 layer:", self.fc3.weight.size())
        return x

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask,labels = batch
        inputs = {'input_ids': input_ids, 'token_type_ids' : token_type_ids, 'attention_mask': attention_mask}
        outputs = self(inputs)
        logits = outputs[0]
        loss = self.criterion(logits, labels)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)  
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask,labels = batch
        inputs = {'input_ids': input_ids, 'token_type_ids' : token_type_ids, 'attention_mask': attention_mask} 
        outputs = self(inputs)
        logits = outputs[0]
        loss = self.criterion(logits, labels)
        preds = torch.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=1)
        accuracy = (preds == labels).float().mean()
        self.log('val_loss', loss)
        self.log('val_acc', accuracy)
        return {"val_loss": loss, "val_acc": accuracy} 

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        return optimizer
```

and i got a RuntimeError: size mismatch (got input: [3], target: [64]) error...how can i resolve this problem??

Logits shape: torch.Size([64, 3])
print(x.shape) = torch.Size([64, 3])

change n_h, change self.fc1= nn.linear() also self.fc3